# Unique identifier of photos in iPhone photo library

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, photolibrary

I am going to develop an app that will basically work as a catalogue for the photos taken from  an iPhone app (saved in photo library). I am thinking about creating an SQLite database (catalogue) and mapping it to photos in the photo library (correct me if this approach is wrong).

What would be the best way to map the photos and the SQLite database?

I want to avoid the case that user changes name of the file and link between file and DB doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can store photos in Base63 string into your SQLite database.

And for the Unique identifier of photos you can user **imagename_curentUnixTimestamp.jpg**.

Comment: I am not sure that storing photos in SQLite is not a good solution, as for the mapping - I want to avoid the case that user changes name of the file and link between file and DB doesn't work anymore.

Comment: so please specify all your requirement in you question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use current date and time to give a name of photo and store it document directory.
also save name of photo into database.when required load photo from document directory as per it's name stored in db.